# Unable to activate SSL mode

Tags: php, openssl, lamp, ftps

I've been trying to use PHP to upload a file to an FTPS server, however I'm continually getting SSL errors. The two methods attempted are below:

```
// METHOD 1
$url = 'ftps://username:pwd@ftpserver/filename.txt';
$context = stream_context_create(array('ftp' => array('overwrite' => true)));
$file_put_contents($url, 'FILE CONTENTS', 0, $context);

// METHOD 2
$ftph = ftp_ssl_connect('ftpserver', 21, 10);
ftp_login($ftph, 'username', 'password');
print ftp_pwd($ftph);
ftp_close($ftph);
```

Error Method 1:

> file_put_contents(ftps://...@ftpserver/filename.txt): failed to open stream: Unable to activate SSL mode in /php/file/directory/index.php on line X

Error Method 2:

> ftp_login(): SSL/TLS handshake failed in /php/file/directory/index.php on line X

In the PHP manual it states that `ftp_ssl_connect` won't exist if PHP wasn't compiled with OpenSSL; PHP isn't complaining that the function doesn't exist, and all indicators from phpinfo point towards OpenSSL being enabled. FileZilla client connects fine with the default port (21), and Encryption: Require explicit FTP over TLS

Running LAMP on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: ssl handshake failed means that SSL **IS** active, but somethign went wrong with the connection. Does the remote site have a valid SSL cert? Most likely PHP won't connect if it's self-signed and the cert can't be validated.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The SSL cert was generated by FileZilla server. Would that be an issue?

Comment: so, yeah, probably self-signed, which most ssl libraries will reject by default. you'll have to mod your stream context to allow self-signing: `'allow_self_signed' => true`

Comment: @MarcB unfortunately I'm still getting the same error. I looked at the FTP server logs, the server gives the message '234 Using authentication type TLS', but doesn't end up establishing the SSL connection. Looking through the manual I may be able to use the 'local_cert' option?